# subprocess a program using another version of python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, maya

I am trying to open a maya file in maya from my python application on osx.

The problem seems to be that since maya is also python based, and uses its own version of python, when it tries to open in the environment of my python app, it behaves unreliably (random errors, python script editor stops working, doesn't really open the intended maya file, etc etc).

I have tried:

```
subprocess.Popen(argList, close_fds = True)
=> maya opens with errors

subprocess.Popen(argList, close_fds = True, shell=True)
=> maya opens with errors

environ = os.environ.copy()
environ["PYTHONPATH"] = ""
subprocess.Popen(argList, close_fds = True, shell=True, env=environ)
=> maya just hangs

environ = os.environ.copy()
environ["PYTHONPATH"] = ""
subprocess.Popen(argList, close_fds = True, shell=False, env=environ)
=> maya just hangs
```

Interestingly, this happens only on osx. On windows everything works with subprocess.Popen(argList, close_fds = True).

What else can I try? How do I get python to open another program without inheriting the environment, i.e., as if I double clicked on the file?

Comment: Are you giving the path to Maya's python as the first argument of arglist?

Comment: No, the arglist is ["/Applications/Autodesk/maya2016/Maya.app/Contents/MacOS/Maya", "path/to/file.ma"]. Maya is a binary, so cannot be given as an input to maya's python - as far as I know, please correct me if I am wrong. I tried it anyway and it spat out a SyntaxError.

Comment: Have you tried ['maya', '-file', 'path/to/file/'] ?  You can also pass a snippet of mel to Maya with the -c flag to dump the current environment vars and let you see what the Maya process thinks is going on.

Comment: Does it work when you just call it from the console? Maybe you need to used `open -a AppName` on OS X.

Comment: It works if I did an open from the terminal, but not if I did a system("open...") from within my python app.

Comment: Most likely running python has set environment variables.  Try running with `env -i`.

Comment: env -i open -a path/to/app path/to/file did it! Thanks stark!

Comment: accept an answer if it solved the problem.